# iphone data storage to remote SQL database server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql-server

I have a task at hand to create a iphone app which is required to do the following.

- the app should get the data entered by the user and store it into a remote server database.
- other app user can see the data in the remote database.
- store login information of the user using the app so as to keep track of what information as uploaded and by who

the thing that i would like to know.

1) What SQL server database is best to accomplish the task.
2) what format is best to retrieve the information from the database.
3) how to send the data from the iphone to the remover server database to it can store the data.

i read up on SQLite and found out that this particular database is a offline which stores the data locally so it cannot be viewed by other used. i wan to use a SQL database which can be accessed remotely.

Answer (score 4):

1) What SQL server database is best to accomplish the task.

**For implementation on server side, you can implement any server database, it does not matter. For implementation on iphone device, you have to implement SQLite database, which will provide storage locally.**

2) what format is best to retrieve the information from the database.

**You can retrieve data using XML or JSON format which will be parsed in device and can be stored in SQLite database, it is the easiest way to transfer data between client and server.**

3) how to send the data from the iphone to the remover server database to it can store the data.

**You can send data from iphone to server in XML/JSON format or by passing parameters in POST or GET request method then this format is parsed on server side and store data on server database.**

For all this, you will require to implement API on server side, which will be the interface between server and device.

Comment: as sqlite  stores information locally i cannot use that as the app i am thinking of desigining should have a access to a central pool of data from where it gets its information if it is stored locally other people using the same app will not be able to see  the data. as you mentioned any server database would be able to do this right any recommendation like which is the best to go along side with the iphone app and Mac OsX and also i am thinking of going live as in is should be accessible remotely and not by the localnetwork (not localhost)

Comment: After retrieval data from server using API, you can store that data locally either temporarily or permanently, for permanent storage, you can implement sqlite database, but remember, this procedure is after retrieval of data from server.

Answer (score 1):

I know you mention SQL specifically, but is this a requirement or just a choice based on what most other people are doing? I ask because personally I would give serious thought to using a NoSQL database (document store) like [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) for such a task. Deploying couch means you often don't need server side application layer at all, the way you will for a SQL based solution.

You talk to couch using HTTP which is perfectly suited to the [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for example. Fetching data is usually a GET request and storing documents is done with PUT. All the data in or out comes back as JSON so [a good JSON library](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/) will make life easier.

The combination of couchdb and the 2 libraries linked above, makes developing a data driven application really, really easy.

That's how I would do it ...

If you really need to stick with SQL, then as Jignesh says, use whatever database you like and implement a suitable API in the server side language of your choice. You can transfer the data however you like although JSON would still get my vote as a relatively light protocol that remains human readable.

Comment: XcodeBeginner here : i do not have any specific sql in mind after reading through and googling most of people are using Mysql (my guess is as it is an open source and free) thats y i mentioned msql. i need a place to store the information like the user entered datetime, location and other information such that when i need the information i can query it and get only the specific information needed.these stored data should be read/write and can be viewed / filtered view by any one using the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud-enabled database service, like [windows azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/05/09/title-now-available-windows-azure-toolkit-for-ios.aspx).

Comment: thax i will check out windows azure